# Show and use different language of button depends on language website (using JavaScript)

Tags: php, wordpress, translate

Thank you in advance for time and attention. I'm learning JS only, so unfortunately have not enogh knowledge yet to do it by myself, so I would be very appreciated if anybody who is exprienced in JS may help.

I have this piece of code by default

```
 <?php 
        if (politicalwp_redux('mt_header_is_donate_active') == 1) {
          # code...
          if (politicalwp_redux('mt_donations_page') != '') {
            $donation_id = politicalwp_redux('mt_donations_page');
            $donation_url = get_permalink( $donation_id );

            echo '<a href="'.esc_url($donation_url).'" class="donate-now">
                    '.esc_attr__('Join us', 'politicalwp').'
                  </a>';
          }elseif (politicalwp_redux('mt_donations_page_custom_url') != '') {
            $donation_url = politicalwp_redux('mt_donations_page_custom_url');
            echo '<a href="'.esc_url($donation_url).'" class="donate-now">
                    '.esc_attr__('Join us', 'politicalwp').'
                  </a>';
          }
        }
        ?>
```

it's a Donation button, I can translate it to a necessary lang using .po and .mo files, but the link will still lead to Egn page. So I am trying to think smith like...if(https://website.com/ru/){ then this button will show in another language and will lead to another url}.
I feel like it should be easy to do, but I don't know how :)

Comment: This code appears to be PHP, not JS...

Comment: oh, right, sure php, sorry, but I think this problem may and should be solved by using JS?

Answer (score 0):

The example you quote(https://website.com/ru/) is made using a route /ru and changing the text on the view

Comment: this is not a real website, it's just example. May you please explain more what do you mean? how to change it on the view?